# reading long types using Java Scanner - character limit?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, long-integer

I'm trying to use Java Scanner to read a 20-digit long from a text file (File.txt).

```
java.util.Scanner filereader = new java.util.Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
longNumber = (long) filereader.nextLong();
```

This returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "37107287533902102798"
at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2271)
at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2225)
at scanner.Scanner.main(Scanner.java:14)
```

When I reduce the length of the number to 19 digits or fewer, it runs just fine. Can someone explain how I can use this for 20+ digits?

Answer (score 6):

`long` can't store numbers of infinite length. It only goes up to `(2^63)-1`. See here: ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

> The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of
>   9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type when you
>   need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

To use that for more digits, you must use a `BigInteger` ([link to documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)).

```
java.util.Scanner filereader = new java.util.Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
bigInt = new BigInteger(filereader.nextLine());
```

Comment: Thanks! for the alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

37107287533902102798 is clearly out of long range, thus you get the exception.

you should be using BigInteger to read such values.

```
BigInteger in = new BigInteger("37107287533902102798");
```

Comment: Thanks! for the alternative too.